# List MP4 by " file '*.mp4' " to a .txt

Tags: command-line, ls, mp4

I want create a `.txt` with all mp4 files of a folder, but vertically and with

```
file '/root/mp4/*.mp4'
```

line by line. 
In Windows it's like

```
(for %i in (*.mp4) do @echo file '%i') > files.txt
```

Comment: Please [edit] and add some lines of example output to your question.

Comment: seems to be an [xy-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) ...

Comment: @mhhhhmaybe Please [edit] your question and describe clearly giving examples what you're trying to achieve, please don't use comments like [below](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033431/list-mp4-by-file-mp4-to-a-txt/1033441#comment1680892_1033432).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the goal right, but if you want every line to read

```bsh
file '/full/path/to/filename.mp4'
```

I suggest to use `find` this way:

```bsh
find ~+ -type f -name "*.mp4" -printf "file\t'%p'\n"
```

This searches the current working directory (`~+` is expanded to the full path by `bash`'s Tilde Expansion) for files whose name matches `*.mp4` and prints them in the specified format: "file" followed by a tab and the filename enclosed in single quotes followed by a newline character – if you want a space instead of the tab, simply substitute `\t` by a space. If you want to store the output in a file `files.txt`, just add `>files.txt` to the command line. Note that this will silently overwrite any existing `files.txt`, if you want to *append* to the file use `>>files.txt` instead.

#### Example output

```bsh
$ find ~+ -type f -name "*.mp4" -printf "file\t'%p'\n"
file    '/home/dessert/test/a.mp4'
file    '/home/dessert/test/b.mp4'
$ find ~+ -type f -name "*.mp4" -printf "file\t'%p'\n" >files.txt
$ cat files.txt 
file    '/home/dessert/test/a.mp4'
file    '/home/dessert/test/b.mp4'
```

---

If you however want `files.txt` to contain the **output** of `file 'some.mp4'`, you can use `file` directly:

```bsh
file *.mp4 >files.txt     # with relative paths
file ~+/*.mp4 >files.txt  # with absolute paths
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
for i in ./*.mp4; do echo "file" \'$(realpath ${i#*\/})\' >> files.txt; done
```

If you don't need `file` in front of each filename, you can use:

```
ls path/to/files/*.mp4 > files.txt
```

Result from first command:

```
file '/home/george/Documents/askubuntu/disk_use.txt'
file '/home/george/Documents/askubuntu/efi_info.txt'
file '/home/george/Documents/askubuntu/empty.txt'
file '/home/george/Documents/askubuntu/fam.txt'
```

#### Note:

- I used `.txt` files, yours will `.mp4`.
- This is run from the folder of interest, if you need to target another please change the line `for i in ./*.mp4` tp for i in /path/to/files/*.mp4`.

Comment: As dessert pointed out in his answer, OP wants the text "file" in front of the filenames in `files.txt`.

Comment: You probably meant `for i in path/to/files/*.mp4`. You can redirect the whole loop's output with `done >> files.txt` (or even `>`), this way the file needs to be opened just once instead of one time for every line.

Comment: Hi, and thank you i have try 
`for i in /root/live/up/*; do echo "file '$i'" >> videos.txt; done` and `for i in /root/live/up/*; do echo -e "file '$i'\n" >> videos.txt; done` for vertically(line by line) but dont work

Comment: i want something like  line 1:file '1.MP4' line 2:file '2.mp4' but `for i in /root/live/up/*; do echo -e "file '$i'\n" >> videos.txt; done` dont make a break line

Comment: @xiota thanks for the edit! IQV i think OP will say what he/she wants

Answer (score 0):

Run this in terminal tried and tested on ubuntu 20

```
printf "file %s\n" *.mp4 > files.txt
```